# Removing Site Map Module

Tags: 7

I'm trying to remove the [Site Map](https://drupal.org/project/site_map) module from my website, however when I disable it in the modules section the page that it generates http://mywebsite.com/sitemap remains unaffected.

My first thought was; maybe the website cache needs clearing and or cron job needs to run. After doing both of those things, nothing has changed. I'm still left with the page on my site that I no longer want.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this? I've even tried deleting the modules folder to no avail.

The module's definitely disabled.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: That's really strange ! sitemap is a menu item defined using hook_menu.. Once you disable the module it shouldn't be accessible.. Are you sure your module is disabled ?

Comment: Yes it's definitely disabled - see screen shot (after refreshing the modules list). @KrishnaMohan how is uninstalling different to disabling and deleting?

Comment: Are you using any cache related modules like boost ?

Comment: I've got boost installed but not enabled.

Comment: @Novocaine88  I've just tried that module for you. After disable the module I got page not found at /sitemap page. So it's working fine for me.

Comment: Is this potentially a different module that's creating the /sitemap page - I assumed it was this module, but as I was not the one to install it I'm not 100% sure???

Comment: If you really did disable the module successfully and you don't have something special caching your pages then whatever is creating that page is not the sitemap module. There is no other explanation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I've got not special caching going on - guess I'll have to do a site wide search for something to do with sitemaps.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might have another module also implementing that path.

To check, install the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) (if you haven't already), and go to /devel/php. Put in this code:

```
foreach (module_implements('menu') as $module) {
  $items = module_invoke($module, 'menu');
  if (isset($items['sitemap'])) {
    print $module;
  }
}
```

And submit the form. If another module is directly responsible for the /sitemap path (i.e. it's not a redirect or something else), its name will be printed to the screen.

Comment: With the module disabled nothing comes up, with it enabled it only shows the one "site_map" which is the correct name of the folder for the module.

Comment: @Novocaine88 - check 'views' list whether there exists a 'view' with '/siteamp' path.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan There was indeed a view for that. I've disabled it and that did change the page. I'm still left with the /sitemap url that shows a title of *Front Page* and a link below for the homepage and an rss.xml feed.

Comment: @Novocaine88 If all else fails, add `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` to your theme's page.tpl.php file and inspect the results on that page. That will tell you exactly which functions (and hence module) was involved in building it

Comment: Ah silly me - the page was still showing up with what I previously said because I hadn't re-disabled the module. So the view *and* the module were both trying to write to that page - with both disabled it no longer exists. Thanks for everyones help.